# Not receiving custom value from Paypal on mobile devices

Tags: paypal

I have a paypal button on my site and I have a custom value that is returned from paypal to my site on completion of the transaction.

It works fine on desktops but for some reason it wont work on mobile devices like an android phone or an Ipad. the payment goes through but the value doesn't seem to be passed to my page.

thanks

Comment: That certainly is strange. If you can please contact me via my profile details so I can gather more details. Once I have more information I can take a look into this further and let you know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out to me. We found there was an issue with the mobile flow not returning data when using RM=2. To retrieve the data you opted to switch to Payment Data Transfer (PDT) to collect the information.

We'll continue working on the issue of returning no Post data while using RM=2 in the mobile flow but at least we got your goal accomplished.

Comment: Hi, is there any news on the issue? I am experiencing quite the same issue – while on desktop, the payment goes through and passes well-formed $_POST array with txn_id, payer_id, verify_sign, mc_gross and custom variables. The return url is set, the automatic return option is on, RM=2 (my setup destroys GET vars, so I can only work with POST).

When on mobile device (in my case iPhone and iPad) the response array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when payments are coming back through from mobile.paypal.com, any get parameters on the 'return' url are being unencoded first, so if there's a %2B in the url I pass to paypal, when it comes back, it's a + (meaning, you're decoding them on your side after the post, then encoding them, instead of simply encoding them).  Same for %3D coming back as =, and I'd assume all sorts of other invalid stuff.  This is not true if the 'return' comes from www.paypal.com.  I'll report a bug, but I'm assuming others will want to know this information.

Chris

Update:  I just got one of these malformed urls from www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr, so it's not just the mobile site...